# How do I add another where clause on this foreach?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Is it possible to add another where clause on this, or do I need to make another foreach?

```
foreach (Point point in _Points.Where(x => x.Name == "Test"))
{
}
```

Basically what I want to add also is where `x.name = "Test"` && where `!x.asset.StartsWith("INV")`

Comment: I believe you've answered your own question: `x => x.Name == "Test" && !x.asset.StartsWith("INV")`

Comment: What occurred when you tried it?

Comment: I was trying to put && x=> !x.Asset.Starts with which was throwing all kinds of errors.

Comment: `foreach` has nothing to do with LINQ or Enumerable, except it can enumerate enumerables. Understand these concepts are separate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just put it in the same Where clause:

```
foreach (Point point in _Points.Where(x => x.Name == "Test" && !x.Asset.StartsWith("INV"))
{
```

Comment: You missing what `x` is. i.e x => x.Name`.

Comment: I've added that part to this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can also chain the LINQ operators

```
foreach (Point point in _Points
    .Where(x => x.Name == "Test")
    .Where(x => !x.asset.StartsWith("INV")))
{

}
```

Sometimes I find it more readable to chain with `Where` instead of messing with lots of `&&` inside one expression.

Also note that good line breaking improves readability in this case.

Comment: I like this, does this slow down performance at all as opposed to the above answer?

Comment: You won't notice any difference. Prioritize readability until you have proven a certain piece of code is actually too slow.

Comment: @mameesh Don't prematurely optimize.  If an application is performing slowly look at places that you can improve it and compare how much you improve performance per developer hour spent.  The performance difference here is so small that it's unlikely to ever be significant enough to bother with.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can as one more where over here

```
foreach (Point point in _Points.Where(x => x.Name == "Test")
                               .Where(x=>!x.asset.StartsWith("INV")))
  {

  }
```

or  better to go for

```
foreach (Point point in _Points.Where(x => x.Name == "Test" && !x.asset.StartsWith("INV")))
  {

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The above will do the trick, but you can also do

```
_Points.Where( x => x.Name == "Test" && !x.Asset.StartsWith("INV")).ToList().ForEach(yourmethod());
```

Comment: This will work with the ToList() call, but I'd argue that it's a very bad idea...   I'd recommend reading: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Comment: Now it works! I still think it's a much worse approach, though: why allocate the memory when you don't need to? `foreach` loops are pretty readable already. Even moreso if you stick the query in a variable: `foreach (var item in myQuery) { .. }` is very straightforward.

Comment: I think we are in fluent vs functional territory here. :)

Comment: @Maess Not quite; the memory allocation is real, and completely unnecessary. Writing a `ForEach()` extension method that operates on `IEnumerable<T>` would change that, though. Anyway, I think you should remove the answer, since the only difference between it and Reed's answer is the bit about `ForEach()`, which isn't really relevant to the poster's question.